# How can I run Linux GUI apps on Ubuntu-touch 16.04 on Nexus 5?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, libertine

I have a Nexus 5 with Ubuntu-touch 16.04.

I mistakenly removed the Desktop Apps app. I can't install it again, because the open store says that my phone doesn't support the app.

So how can I run Linux GUI apps, with libertine or natively?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to install the scope separately any more. If you open the scopes overview/manager by swiping up from bottom edge on the dash, you can favorite the already installed desktop apps scope, to see the list of apps in your libertine containers again.